# WPF : render report in PDF format

Tags: wpf, rdlc, wpf-4.0

I am working with WPF rdlc , currently I am using `windowformhost` `reportviewer` to show my report . If I need to view in PDF form I will export to PDF through the report viewer by clicking the export button .

Is that anyway to show the report directly in a PDF form instead of doing all the steps above ?

I am using VS2013 as development tools

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You want to first use the ReportViewer to render the report, then stream it to file. Once it's written to file, you can open the pdf from the file system.

Export is something along these lines:

```
byte[] renderedBytes = rptViewer.LocalReport.Render(
    "PDF",
    "<DeviceInfo><ExpandContent>True</ExpandContent></DeviceInfo>",
    out mimeType,
    out encoding,
    out fileNameExtension,
    out streams,
    out warnings);

using (FileStream fsExport = new FileStream(@"C:\MyLocation\MyReport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    fsExport.Write(wordbytes, 0, wordbytes.Length);
}
```

Now you simply open up the pdf file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\MyLocation\MyReport.pdf")
```